# Demonstrating that a function is holomorphic at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let E be a closed bounded subset of the complex plane over which area can be defined:

$$ f(w)=\iint \frac{dxdy}{w-z}$$ where we are integrating over E, and w is an element of E complement.

The goal is to show that f is holomorphic at infinity and to find the coefficients of the power series representation of f centered at infinity.

I notice that the form of the integral is similar to Cauchy's integral formula, and I want to put $$ g(z)=f(1/z) $$ and solve for the coefficients of the power series for g centered at 0. Could someone please give me a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac 1 {w-z}=-\frac 1 z \frac 1 {1-\frac w z}=-\frac 1 z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac w n)^{n}$ provide $|z| >\sup \{|c|: c \in E\}$. Integrate this to conclude that $f(\frac 1 z)$ is holomorphic to $0$.